# Is it possible to rename the fields on message triggered running of debezium mysql connector?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have configured a debezium mysql connector, I need to include additonal field as table name in the payload. What configuration change i need to do achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table name is already included, in the `source.table` element. [Here's](https://rmoff.net/2018/03/24/streaming-data-from-mysql-into-kafka-with-kafka-connect-and-debezium/) a sample message of an insert to a table called `rental`:

```
{
  "before": null,
  "after": {
    "fullfillment.sakila.rental.Value": {
      "rental_id": 13346,
      "rental_date": 1124483301000,
      "inventory_id": 4541,
      "customer_id": 131,
      "return_date": {
        "long": 1125188901000
      },
      "staff_id": 2,
      "last_update": "2006-02-15T21:30:53Z"
    }
  },
  "source": {
    "name": "fullfillment",
    "server_id": 0,
    "ts_sec": 0,
    "gtid": null,
    "file": "mysql-bin.000002",
    "pos": 832,
    "row": 0,
    "snapshot": {
      "boolean": true
    },
    "thread": null,
    "db": {
      "string": "sakila"
    },
    "table": {
      "string": "rental"
    }
  },
  "op": "c",
  "ts_ms": {
    "long": 1518190060267
  }
}
```

If you want to insert additional fields you can use the [`InsertField$Value`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html) Single Message Transform, which you can see an example of in [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/).

---

Edit:

If you want the field in a different part of the message you have a few options. You could post-process the data with Kafka Streams to restructure it as you desire. You could use available Single Message Transform to flatten the `after` component and then add in static values:

```
            "transforms": "unwrap,InsertTopic,InsertSourceDetails",
            "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
            "transforms.InsertTopic.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
            "transforms.InsertTopic.topic.field":"messagetopic",
            "transforms.InsertSourceDetails.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
            "transforms.InsertSourceDetails.static.field":"messagesource",
            "transforms.InsertSourceDetails.static.value":"Debezium CDC from Oracle on asgard"
```

Or you could write your own Single Message Transform to do exactly the modifications you're wanting to do.

Comment: Is there a way to add this field in the after node, like after.table ?